# Tangent line solution at a given set of points?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is homework, but the problem set is already due, but I don't understand how to get the answer to this problem and I'd really like to understand the thought process behind disseminating this problem.

```
    On your own paper, sketch the graph of the parabola 
y = x^2 +8
. On the same graph, plot the point 
(0, −3)
. Note that there are two tangent lines of y that pass through this point. (It may be useful to sketch them on your graph.)

Specifically, the tangent line of the parabola 
y = x^2 +8
 at the point 
(a, a^2+8)
 passes through the point 
(0, −3)
where a>0. The other tangent line passing through this point goes through 
(−a, a^2+8)
.

Use this information to find the number a.
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your exercise suggested, suppose that $(a,a^2+8)$ is a point of tangency. If $y=x^2+8$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x$.

So the slope of the tangent line at $(2a,a^2+8)$ is $2a$.

It follows that the tangent line has equation
$$y-(a^2+8)=2a(x-a).$$
We can rewrite this equation as 
$$y=2ax+8-a^2.\tag{$1$}$$ 
The above line passes through $(0,-3)$.
Substitute these values of $x$ and $y$ in Equation $(1)$ . We get a quadratic equation in $a$. Solve for $a$. In this case,  we get $-3=(2a)(0)+8-a^2$. So $a^2=11$ and therefore $a=\pm\sqrt{11}$.
The $\pm$ makes sense, because of the symmetry of the picture about the $y$-axis: the points of tangency must be symmetrical about the $y$-axis.

For each of these values of $a$, substitute in Equation $(1)$ to find our two tangent lines.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful!